# Turn a pointer array into an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I need to be able to turn this char* array[SIZE] into a char* example. How can i do this? 
My problem is that i need to be able to manage the contents of array separately in a pointer like fashion
For example if i have:

```
array[0] = "dog"
array[1] = "cat"
array[2] = "one"
```

i want to be able to access each one of those elements by incrementing the value of a pointer
like this

```
example = "dog"
example++ = "cat"
example++ = "one"
```

thanks in advance!!

My main problem is that i need to have all of these values pointed by a pointer, such that when i print my pointer ill have something like this:

```
printf("example: %s\n", example);
output: example: dog cat one
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do:

```
char **example=array;
```

of course it's not a `char *` (which you asked in the first line), but it does allow the functionality you ask for later.

--- edit ---
Your printf requirement cannot be met with this method. In C++ you could build some strange object that would meet both requirements (but with C++ streams, not printf), but you should explain the "big picture", this whole thing smells a lot of XY problem.

Comment: the problem that i encountered by doing it that way is that i get a segmentation error. How could i avoid getting a seg error?

Comment: @user2913269: how would I know? It all depends on how is the rest of your code.

Comment: @AndreyT: that requirement has been added after my answer was posted.

Comment: Matteo i apologize for that, but i forgot to mention that my program has to be able to move the pointer word by word, and utilize that value as i go

Comment: @user2913269: The pointer in the above answer will move word-by-word. However, these words will not be stored as one string. They will be stored as separate words. Your last requirement - the ability to print all words in one shot - is the part that makes no sense and makes the whole thing impossible. Remove that strange requirement and Matteo's answer becomes exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are mutually exclusive.

It is not possible to have an array of pointers to zero-terminated strings that is at the same time printable "in one shot", as in your `printf` example.

You will have to reconsider your approach. What you want at this point is not possible.